# Gradle 1.3: build.gradle not building classes

Tags: linux, eclipse, build-automation, gradle

a newb question here:  I have a build.gradle file with `apply plugin: java` in it, and associated with a java project/package. when I run `gradle build` from the command line I get:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE 
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.312 secs
```

but when I check the build folder, there are no classes. What am I doing wrong ?

I have:
lib, reports, test-results & tmp under the folder but no classes. The src code is a class with a main method with 'Hello world' printed to console...

My tree looks like this:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── gradle-sandbox.jar
│   ├── reports
│   │   └── tests
│   │       ├── base-style.css
│   │       ├── css3-pie-1.0beta3.htc
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── report.js
│   │       └── style.css
│   ├── test-results
│   └── tmp
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
└── src
└── org
    └── gradle
        └── example
            └── simple
                ├── HelloWorld.java
                └── package-info.java
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without more information, it's hard to say. Maybe you put the source file into the wrong directory (default is `src/main/java`). Or the internal caches got corrupted (shouldn't happen, but try to delete the `.gradle` directory).

Do you get class files when you do `gradle clean build`? Note that a clean build is required whenever you switch between Gradle versions.

Comment: what other info would you need ? I did a gradle clean build and I get the same result. And the gradle file is under the src project.

Comment: I guess the source file path is `src/org/gradle/example/simple/HelloWorld.java`. (The diagram shows something different.) That doesn't match Gradle's default, so you'll have to reconfigure it: `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src"]`

Comment: And to answer your other question, it helps a lot if you show the relevant parts of the build script.

Comment: @Niederweiser, thanks. I am just doing a really simple hello world. The only thing in it is what is mentioned above 'apply plugin: java'

Comment: I added that little bit of code to my build.gradle and I get the HelloWorld.class! Your the man!

Comment: Thanks! I stupidly put my java hierarchy in src/main instead of src/main/java and nothing was obviously being compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where all of my classes were in **src/main/java** but none of the classes were showing up in the jar.

Issue was I was using Groovy. Adjusting it to **src/main/groovy** resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where I was already following the above hierarchy but also putted build.gradle inside the srcm/main/java/{{my project}}.  Moving build.gradle to the project's root directory worked for me.

Let me know if it'll work for anyone else.