# Gradle builds, then ignores sub-project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project in `big-project/` and a sub-project in `big-project/lib/`.

In `big-project/`'s `big.project.Main` class I `import big.project.lib.Utils`, which is defined in the `big-project/lib/` sub-project.

When I try to run `gradle build`, this is what happens:

```
:lib:
compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:lib:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:lib:classes UP-TO-DATE
:lib:jar
:compileJava
big-project/src/main/java/big/project/Main.java:3: error: package big.project.lib not exist
import big.project.lib.Utils;
                      ^
1 error
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.243 secs
```

For some reason, gradle compiles the code of the subproject, and then decides to ignore it. **How do I fix that?**

These are my gradle files:

`big-project/settings.gradle`:

```
include 'lib'
```

`big-project/build.gradle`:

```
evaluationDependsOnChildren()

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    version = '1.0'

    group = 'big.project'
}

apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies {
    compile project(':lib')
}
```

`big-project/lib/build.gradle` is empty

---

I did study the gradle manual: [Chapter 56. Multi-project Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), but nothing useful came from this.

Comment: Typically in multi-project builds the root project does not contain source code and acts only to coordinate the build. Try adding another subproject for your root's source code. Technically your solution should work based on what "Decoupled Projects" states, but since decoupling will eventually be mandatory its best to do so now (this transition may be the cause for your problem)

Comment: I tried to move that code to `big-project/product`, but I still get the same error. I revisited sections [56.9. Decoupled Projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects) and [56.7. Project lib dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#javadependencies_2), but that did not help; regardless if I put the `compile project(':lib')` into the `big-project/product/build.grade`, or into the `big-project/build.gradle`. (PS: I did add the `product` project to `big-project/settings.gradle`)

Comment: Unfortunately without seeing the build scripts, all I can do is point you to an example [project](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) for how a multi-project build should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: My `big-project/lib/src` folder wasn't set up correctly (source code was in the wrong sub directory). As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754696/1296709) states, Java sources need to be in `src/main/java`.

Thanks to comments on the question I was able to look in the right place for a solution. As suggested, I looked at a working sample project. As I was using Eclipse, I generated a new Gradle project based on the `flat-java-multiproject` sample. This enabled me to eliminate my `build.gradle` files as the source of the error.

Next, I decided to inspect the `build/` artifacts of the `lib/` project and discovered that the `.jar` file did not contain any `.class` files. That explains the compiler error I reported in the question. This caused my to see if all `.java` sources were in the right place, and as mentioned above, they weren't. Fixing this, fixed the compiler error.

The whole crux was that while I was writing my code in eclipse, all references to the `lib` project's classes seemed to be found.